# How can i stop firebase getting data from local caching

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There was a null user in my firebase table and some of devices fetched that and crashing since. I  deleted that user. Is there any way i can fix this without updating the build.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")

ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapShot: DataSnapshot!) in

    let totalUsers = snapShot.childrenCount
    self.usersRefHandle = ref.observe(.childAdded , with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

        print(snapshot.key)
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you have [disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence) enabled, and the cached `null` value in the cache is making the app crash?

Comment: Yes, Actually i want to stop firebase sing caching data on applications that are running on device without updating them.

Comment: I don't see how the code you shared would cause an exception for a missing value. Can you include the exact stack trace in the question?